# need VHDL equivalent of c-language "strtok" and "strcmp" functions that can operator on vhdl string type

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to write a stimulus reader for vhdl testbench.  it needs to read a text command and two text operands delimited by whitespaces in a text file.

```
entity tb is
end entity;

architecture sim is tb of
begin

process
    variable L        : line;
    file     STIMFILE : test is in "stim.txt";
    variable s1       : string;
    variable s2       : string;
    variable s3       : string;
begin

    while not endfile(STIMFILE) loop
        readline(STIMFILE, L);

        s1 := strtok(L, "\n\t ");
        s2 := strtok(0, "\n\t ");
        s3 := strtok(0, "\n\t ");

        if (strcmp(s1, "ADDXYZ") = '1') then
            report "ADDXYZ " & s2 & " " & s3;
        end if;
    end loop;

end process;

end architecture;
```

How would I do this in VHDL?

so far i have a function for strcmp:

```
FUNCTION strcmp(s1: STRING; s2: STRING)    --string compare 
    RETURN BOOLEAN IS 
  BEGIN 
    IF(s1'LENGTH /= s2'LENGTH) THEN 
      RETURN FALSE; 
    ELSE 
      FOR i IN s1'RANGE LOOP 
        IF(s1(i) /= s2(i)) THEN 
          RETURN FALSE; 
        END IF; 
      END LOOP; 
      RETURN TRUE; 
    END IF; 
  END;   --function strcmp
```

Comment: similar idea... https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tokenize_a_string#Ada

Comment: Your strcmp looks eerily like an overload for the equality operator implicitly declared for a type (here in std.standard, see IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2.3 Relational operators, 16.3 Package STANDARD) You could use an alias instead. `alias strcmp is std.standard."=" [string, string return boolean];` You can then use strcmp as a function call using positional association e.g. `strcmp("string1", "string2")` (named association cannot be used for parameters of a predefined operator, 9.2 Operators, 9.2.1 General).

Comment: I had to rewrite it anyways because it doesn't recognize zero-terminated strings in a fixed sized string buffer.  if only vhdl had direct mapping of c language functions to hdl functions like system verilog DPI.  As far as i know, it only supports the old FLI/PLI like interfaces with all the strange accesser functions to poke at the simulation data structure in memory.

Comment: The -1987 standard shared 60 percent of it's text with the Ada83 LRM. Writing programs in VHDL for verification wasn't a goal. Abstract types based on enumeration with positional value are fine for formal proofs. VHDL was originally a library allowing Ada to be used as a programming language incidentally compatible with VHDL's strong typing and capable of sharing packages. HW and verification uses imperfectly overlapping subsets of HDLs of which none scale well in the face of Moore's Law or design complexity.

Answer (score 2):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use std.textio.all;

package pkg_fancy_strings is

    -- Max Line length to tokenize
    constant STRTOK_MAX : natural := 200;

    procedure line2string(L: inout line; S: out string);

    function is_space (c:character) return boolean;
    function is_nul   (c:character) return boolean;

    -- structure to maintain state between strtok calls
    type strtok_t is
    record
        str   : string(1 to STRTOK_MAX);  --input string
        pos   : natural;                  --input string iterator position
        more  : boolean;                  --call strtok_next until more equals false stop 
        tok   : string(1 to STRTOK_MAX);  --token string value
        len   : natural;                  --token string length
        valid : boolean;                  --token string valid
        error : natural;                  --token string had an error, ex: truncation
    end record;

    -- return string of length n padded with nul if less than n originally
    function strpad(n: natural; x: string; rm_comment: boolean) return string;

    -- Initialize strtok structure with unparsed string
    function strtok_init(s : string) return strtok_t;

    -- tokenize string in strtok buffer
    function strtok_next(t: strtok_t) return strtok_t;

    -- compare strings  
    function strcmpi(s1: string; s2: string)  return boolean;   

    -- convert string into integer
    function str2integer(s: string) return integer;

end package;


package body pkg_fancy_strings is


    function is_space(c:character) return boolean is
    begin
        if (c = ' ') then
            return true;
        end if;

        if (c <= character'val(13)) then
           return true;
        end if;

        return false;        
    end function;

    function is_nul(c:character) return boolean is
    begin
        if (c = character'val(0)) then
            return true;
        end if;

        return false;        
    end function;

    procedure line2string(L: inout line; S: out string) is
        variable good  :boolean;
        variable ch    :character;
        variable str   :string(1 to STRTOK_MAX);
        variable i     :integer := 1;
        variable len   :integer := 0;
    begin

        -- Zero Line Buffer
        for i in 1 to str'length loop
            str(i) := character'val(0);
        end loop;

        len := 1;           
        loop 

            read(L, ch, good);
            if (good = false) then
                exit;
            end if;

            str(len) := ch;
            len      := len + 1;

            if (is_nul(ch)) then
               exit;
            end if;

            if (len > str'length-1) then
                exit;
            end if;

        end loop;

        S := str;

    end procedure;

    -- return string of length n padded with nul if less than n originally
    function strpad(n: natural; x: string; rm_comment: boolean) 
        return string is
        variable r:    string(1 to n);
        variable stop: natural;
    begin
        for i in 1 to n loop
            r(i) := character'val(0);
        end loop;

        stop := x'length;
        if (stop >= n) then
          stop := n-1;
        end if;

        for i in 1 to stop loop
            -- ignore everything on line after '#'
            if (x(i) = '#') then
               exit;
            end if;
            r(i) := x(i);
        end loop;

        return r;
    end function;



    -- Initialize strtok structure with unparsed string
    function strtok_init(
        s : string
    ) return strtok_t is
        variable t  :strtok_t;
        variable i  :natural;
        variable ch :character;
    begin

        t.str   := strpad(STRTOK_MAX, s, true);
        t.pos   := 1;
        t.more  := true;
        t.valid := false;  --tok string not valid yet
        t.error := 0;
        return t;

    end function;

    -- tokenize string in strtok buffer
    function strtok_next(
        t: strtok_t
    ) return strtok_t is
        variable ch   :character := character'val(0);
        variable i    :natural   := 0;
        variable r    :strtok_t;

    begin    
        r := t;

        -- Zero t.tok
        r.len := 0;
        for i in 1 to r.tok'length loop
            r.tok(i) := character'val(0);
        end loop;

        -- Eat Spaces
        loop
            if (r.pos > r.str'length-1) then
                r.valid    := false;
                r.more     := false;
                return r;
            end if;

            ch := r.str(r.pos);           

            if (is_nul(ch) = true) then
                r.valid    := false;
                r.more     := false;
                return r;
            end if;

            if (is_space(ch) = false) then
               exit;
            else 
               r.pos    := r.pos + 1;           
            end if;
        end loop; 

        -- Save Token
        i    := 1;
        loop
              if (i > r.tok'length-1) then
                r.valid    := true;
                r.more     := true;
                r.error    := 1;
                return r;
            end if;

            if ((r.pos > r.str'length) or is_nul(r.str(r.pos))) then
                r.valid    := (r.tok'length /= 0);
                r.more     := false;
                r.error    := 0;
                return r;
            end if;

            ch := r.str(r.pos);           
            if (is_space(ch)) then
                r.valid    := true;
                r.more     := true;
                r.error    := 0;
                return r;
            else 
               r.tok(i) := ch;
               r.len    := i;
               i        := i + 1;
               r.pos    := r.pos + 1;           
            end if;
        end loop; 

        -- shouldn't get here    
        r.error    := 2;
        r.valid    := false;
        r.more     := false;
        return r;   

    end function;

    --string compare
    function strcmpi(s1: string; s2: string)     
        return boolean is
        variable max: natural := 0;
        variable end_s1:boolean;
        variable end_s2:boolean;
        variable nul_s1:boolean;
        variable nul_s2:boolean;
    begin 
        if (s1'length >= s2'length) then  max := s1'length; else max := s2'length; end if;

        for i in 1 to max loop 
            end_s1 := (i > s1'length);
            end_s2 := (i > s2'length);

            if (end_s1 and end_s2) then return true; end if;

            if (end_s1) then
                nul_s2 := (s2(i) = character'val(0));
                if (nul_s2) then return true; end if;
            end if;

            if (end_s2) then
                nul_s1 := (s1(i) = character'val(0));
                if (nul_s1) then return true; end if;
            end if;

            nul_s1 := (s1(i) = character'val(0));
            nul_s2 := (s2(i) = character'val(0));

            if (nul_s1 and nul_s2) then return true; end if;

            if(s1(i) /= s2(i)) then 
              return false; 
            end if; 

        end loop; 

        return true;
    end function;

    -- read next whitespace delimited string
    --     return string is terminated with null's
    procedure read_string(L: inout Line; s: out string(1 to 80); 
                 good: out boolean) is
        variable c     :character;      
        variable r     :string(1 to 80);
        variable i     :natural;
    begin
        r := (others => character'val(0));
        s := (others => character'val(0));

        -- Skip WhiteSpace
        loop
            read(L, c, good);
            report "c:" & character'image(c);
            if (good = False) then
                good := False;
                return;
            elsif ((c = ' ') or (c <= character'val(13)) ) then
                next;
            end if;
            exit;
        end loop;

        -- Read Until Non-Whitespace
        i    := 1;
        r(i) := c;
        i    := i+1;
        loop
            read(L, c, good);
            if (good = false) then
                s    := r;
                good := True;               
                return;
            elsif ((c = ' ') or (c <= character'val(13)) ) then
                s := r;
                good := True;               
                return;
            else 
                r(i) := c;
                i    := i + 1;
            end if;
        end loop;

    end procedure;

end package body;

-- EXAMPLE OF FANCY STRINGS USAGE:
--
--    use work.pkg_fancy_strings.all;
--    
--    entity tb is
--    end entity;
--    
--    architecture rtl of tb is
--    begin
--        process
--          file      stim_in        :text open read_mode is "testcase1.txt";
--          variable  L              :line;
--          variable  sbuf           :string(1 to STRTOK_MAX);
--          variable  slen           :natural;
--          variable  t              :strtok_t;
--        begin
--            t := strtok_init("   mary had a little #lamb");
--            while(t.more) loop        
--                t := strtok_next(t);
--                if (t.valid) then
--                    report ">>" & t.tok(1 to t.len) & "<<";
--                end if;
--            end loop;
--        
--            report "done." severity failure;
--        end process;
--    end architecture;
--
```

Comment: Please explain your source code and/or add an origin and/or add copyright notes.

Comment: you are free to use it how ever you want...it only about 20 minutes to write this code from scratch...